# Create safe authentication in Angular app with NodeJS API

Tags: encryption, web-application, jwt

I develop an Angular app with a NodeJS API.

I am trying to add security to my application and so I need to create a safe authentication. To do it I have found some courses to add JWT to requests and especially followed [this one](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/). I have then created verification middleware on express API and token storage in Angular localStorage to check the user expiration.

I have heard some possibility to refresh tokens to not have to relog after few minutes but to refresh the token and relog only after a week for example.

I also need to add some encryption to password and some sensitive data.

So I am looking for courses, advice or anything that can help me in the doing of a safe application.

Don't know if that help but this web application will be used with ElectronJS so it will be more a software than a real web application.